# What's wrong with my PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to pull a specific link from a feed where all of the content is on one line and there are multiple links present.  The one I want has the content of "[link]" in the the A tag.  Here's my example:

```
<a href="google.com/">test1</a> <a href="google.com/">test2</a> <a href="http://www.amazingpage.com/">[link]</a> <a href="google.com/">test3</a><a href="google.com/">test4</a>
... could be more links before and/or after
```

How do I isolate just the href with the content "[link]"?

This regex goes to the correct end of the block I want, but starts at the first link:

```
(?<=href\=\").*?(?=\[link\])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Also could try `href="\K[^"]*(?="[^<]*\[link\])` [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bI7qG2/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this updated regex:

```
(?<=href\=\")[^<]*?(?=\">\[link\])
```

See [demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/pZ1gK9/1).
The problem is that the dot matches too many characters and in order to get the right 'href' you need to just restrict the regex to `[^<]*?`.

Comment: (?<=href\=["'])[^<]*?(?=['"]>\[link\]) will do both quotes (I think)

Comment: @MichaelICE: Yes, that is a good idea, but it all depends on the input. If the attributes cannot be enclosed in single quotes, there is no point in complicating the regex pattern and decreasing performance.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively :)

This code :

```
$string = '<a href="google.com/">test1</a> <a href="google.com/">test2</a> <a href="http://www.amazingpage.com/">[link]</a> <a href="google.com/">test3</a><a href="google.com/">test4</a>';
$regex = '/href="([^"]*)">\[link\]/i';
$result = preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Will return :

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(41) "href="http://www.amazingpage.com/">[link]"
  [1] =>
  string(27) "http://www.amazingpage.com/"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using regular expression and use [**DOM**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to do this.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <a href="google.com/">test1</a>
     <a href="google.com/">test2</a>
     <a href="http://www.amazingpage.com/">[link]</a>
     <a href="google.com/">test3</a>
     <a href="google.com/">test4</a>
');

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
   if ($link->nodeValue == '[link]') {
     echo $link->getAttribute('href');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With DOMDocument and XPath:

```
$dom = DOMDOcument::loadHTML($yourHTML);
$xpath = DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//a[. = "[link]"]/@href') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

or if you are looking for only one result:

```
$dom = DOMDOcument::loadHTML($yourHTML);
$xpath = DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList = $xp->query('//a[. = "[link]"][1]/@href');
if ($nodeList->length) 
    echo $nodeList->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

xpath query details:

```
//a              # 'a' tag everywhere in the DOM tree
[. = "[link]"]   # (condition) which has "[link]" as value 
/@href           # "href" attribute
```

The reason your regex pattern doesn't work:

The regex engine walks from left to right and for each position in the string it tries to succeed. So, even if you use a non-greedy quantifier, you obtain always the leftmost result.